# is the chromebook developer mode shell a fully capable linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, chromebook

I have enabled developer mode on my chromebook. Is the command line shell a fully implemented linux shell? Would there be any point in installing something like ubuntu?

Comment: Well, if all you need is a shell, then installing Ubuntu might be an overkill and yes, the bash is bash even on ChromeOS. On the other hand should you want to use your Chromebook as a regular laptop without Google's stuff, then installing Ubuntu is a good option. I have opted for staying clear from ChromeOS on my chromebooks and run Ubuntu instead.

Comment: Thanks sami. I may end up going with ubuntu anyway. I haven't found a nice text editor for chrome.